# Creating Room Database per user in Android

Tags: android, android-room

I tried to implement a multi-account application using the ROOM database. So, I decided to create a ROOM database object per user, such as:

```kotlin
val appDatabaseName = "myapp" + getUserUin()
AppDatabase appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, appDatabaseName).build()

Global.setAppDatabase(appDatabaseName)// using this object for later transactions
```

When the user tries to logout or switch accounts, then I called:

```kotlin
Global.getAppDatabase().close() // try to close the ROOM object
```

Then repeat the same process to keep the room object when the user logins successfully. But It sometimes comes with

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.`

But I have no idea why it happens.

So I am wondering,

1. Should I close the Room Database object once the user logout/switch account? Can I leave it to the system to close all the Room objects I created?
2. If I can't, how do I solve this exception?

Comment: But what disadvantages do you see in using single database with user_id in its tables? What are the real benefits in your decision "database per user"?

Comment: I think entities in my application don't care about user_id, if I put user_id in tables, when I insert into tables then I should set the user_id correctly. I would rather separate the database instance by user_id. Mixing all user data in one database seems a mess.